# numbers and next line only in the textarea field

Tags: php, string, numbers, textarea, preg-match

I m trying to use following pattern

```
65465465465654
6546465465465465
5646545646464
6545646456
6454646456
```

in text area 
please anyone help me 
to check preg_match pattern
for the above input type

I want to take mobile numbers separated by the next line character.

Comment: You could try `/^(\d+)$/mg`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$numbers = "65465465465654
6546465465465465
5646545646464
6545646456
6454646456";

preg_match_all("/([0-9]*)\n/", $numbers, $resultArray);

foreach ($resultArray as $result) {
    preg_replace("/\n/", "", $result);
}
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "65465465465654"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "6546465465465465"
  [2]=>
  string(13) "5646545646464"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "6545646456"
}
```

Comment: @Badrinath Please remember to mark the question to "Accepted" and upvote it. That would help others.